# How can I intercept/redirect a keystroke in PySide/Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am writing a simple app in PySide/Qt. I want an application-wide shortcut that will catch a specific keystroke (Page Down) and send it to a specific widget (textEdit).

In other words, if someone presses the Page Down key, I want the text in the textEdit (which is read-only) to scroll.

I have **no** idea how to accomplish this. Any help/hints would be **greatly** appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There are many other examples on SO of implementing shortcuts for various effects. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631601/how-to-program-custom-keyboard-shortcuts; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674282/keyboard-events-qmainwindow-inside-qmainwindow?noredirect=1&lq=1; and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914809/how-to-propagate-keypressevent-on-different-qt-qmainwindow?rq=1, for starters.

Comment: [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html).

Comment: I know how to create a shortcut (but thanks for the link). What I **don't** know how to do is send a keystroke (in this case Page Down) to a widget,

Comment: After a lot of googling (is that a word) and experimentation, I got it worked out...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
self.pgdwn = QShortcut(self)
self.pgdwn.setKey(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Down))
self.pgdwn.activated.connect(lambda: self.on_page_down())

def on_page_down(self):
    self.sendkeys(Qt.Key_PageDown)

def sendkeys(self, char, modifier=Qt.NoModifier):
    event = QKeyEvent(QEvent.KeyPress, char, modifier)
    QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.textEdit, event)
```